# Can't add android platforms in cordova 3.5.0

Tags: android, cordova

here is the information shown in my commandline:

```
     $ cordova platforms add android
     Creating android project...
     Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 'C:\Users\Administrator\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\VERSION'
        at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
        at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:284:15)
        at c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\platform.js:351:42
        at _fulfilled (c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:798:54)
        at self.promiseDispatch.done (c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30)
        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:760:13)
        at c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:821:14
        at flush (c:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:108:17)
        at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
        at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First go to that path and see if the file it's looking for is indeed missing.

`C:\Users\Administrator\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.5.0\VERSION`

If it is then reinstall cordova using the following commands:

```
npm uninstall cordova -g
npm cache clean
npm install cordova -g
```

Then try again and see if you get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

SyntheCyphers answer worked for me after manually deleting the whole .cordova folder and then running `cordova platform add android` in project folder.

Answer (score 1):

When u create a project in cordova 3.5.0, version file in .cordova is missing. 
So unable to add android platform. I have copied version file from 3.4.0 and paste it to 3.5.0 with version change as 3.5.0. and with it, my issue is solved.